# RTCmulticonnection use existing getUserMedia stream

Tags: javascript, socket.io, stream, webrtc, rtcmulticonnection

I prepared a webcam streaming app and therefore previewed a users webcam in a video tag using "navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia".

After the user hits a button and "RTCmulticonnection" opens a room, I want to add the preview webcam / video to be used as webcam-stream.

I just don't get it working.

The part Im going to show you starts after the socket.io Connection is established - the "connection.open" method also returns that the room has been created and the connection is established. So Signaling works - I just don't know how to simply attach my Video to the (RTCmulsiconnection) connection Object.

I have tried to use the "attachStreams" method, but remained unsuccessfully.

```
//Get Users Webcam
 navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: true,
    video: true
}).then(function(stream) {
    $("#mediaPreview").show();
    let preview = document.getElementById('mediaPreviewVideo');
    preview.srcObject = stream;
    preview.volume = 0;
    preview.play();
});

//Start stream
$("#btnMediaStreamStart").on('click', function(e) {

            //Prevent Default & Hide
            e.preventDefault();

            //Add Classes
            $("#mediaPreviewVideo").addClass('webcam-online');
            $("#mediaStreamStatus").show().addClass('bg-success').html('<small><strong>Live</strong></small>');

            connection.socketURL = 'localhost:9001/';
            let connectionRoom = '123';
            connection.open(connectionRoom, function(e) {
                if (e === true) {
                    connection.attachStreams.forEach(function(localStream) {
                        //How to attach the cam stream? Is my previously created video even part of the "streams"?
                    });
                    connection.mediaConstraints = {
                        audio: {
                            deviceId: selectAudio
                        },
                        video: {
                            deviceId: selectVideo
                        }
                    };
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
connection.addStream(stream);
```

where `stream` is your already captured stream - perhaps via `getUserMedia()`